# How big should my sample size be?

Tags: sample-size

I'd like to replicate the following research but need help calculating my sample size. Not sure how to do so without knowing the Standard Deviation and having multiple groups. I was told this online calculator could help but I'm not sure what to input.
It seems more calculations are needed before getting to a point where I can use this calculator.  Somehow using confidence interval to get standard deviation?  But of what group?
[https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~rollin/stats/ssize/n2.html](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/%7Erollin/stats/ssize/n2.html)

The mean for the variable I'm investigating is:
1.520 for Healthy Females (43 Participants)
2.516 for Injured Females (51 Participants)
1.445 for Healthy Males (40 Participants)
2.286 for Injured Males (41 Participants)

The 95% Confidence Interval is:
1.387-1.653 for Healthy Females
1.916-3.007 for Injured Females
1.319-1.569 for Healthy Males
1.801-2.775 for Injured Males

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks for the input already. This is the study I'm looking at.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7733539/
I'm not looking to replicate exactly, they used two different groups (healthy and injured) whereas I'm looking to study the same individuals before and after injury (concussion), so I'm trying to determine how many athletes I need to recruit (based on a 10-15% concussion rate) and compare the same individuals to themselves.

Comment: 1) What kind of confidence interval is that? 2) What research do you want to replicate? You did not give a citation. 3) What to do you want to be able to detect? 4) Why not use the sample sizes used in the original work?

Comment: To add to @Dave's questions, one thing the calculator will need to know is the effect size you anticipate.  What is the effect in this experiment?  What are you comparing to what?